# IIS and Flash forceSmoothing issue

Tags: flash, iis

I am incorporating a Flash Flickr Polaroid file into my site, 
http://www.no3dfx.com/polaroid/

But I am having problems with the images being smooth. I have edited the code throughout with forceSmoothing = true and _quality = best.

It all works and looks smooth if I test the file in the preview window and if I run the HTML file. But as soon as I put the file under IIS the smoothing stops.

All my flash players are v10+

I have turned the IIS compression off but no luck.

Can anyone please help with this?

Thanks,

Clyde

Answer (score 0):

well this is something that could be related to the bitmap class generation, where you can set it do the smoothing. But to give you any more info, I would at least need to know what version of actionscript you're using. in AS3 you could just set it like I mentioned, but in as2 there's a bit of a workaround where you have to trick flash into smoothing the pictures that are loaded dynamically.